# Excel shuts down in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, microsoft-excel

I have written an employee payroll program using Excel 2000. It runs fine on my computer running Vista. When I port it via a flash drive to a Windows 7 computer and run it from the flash drive, it runs OK the first time. After closing it and reopeinig it, it starts and then a Message box appears "Microsoft Excel has stopped working"  with a Cancel button. After a while this box closes and a second box opern "Microsort Excel for Windows has stopped working"  with a Close button.

Then when I try to run the save program from the Win 7 machine on my Vista machine, I get the same result "Excel shutting down.

Comment: Are you copying just the XLS file to the Win7 machine, or did you take all of Excel 2000?  If just the file, what version of Excel is running on the Win7 machine?  Does your payroll program use VBA or Macros, or is it all formula based?

Comment: Excel 2000 is installed on both machines.  I'm copying the xls file between machines.  The program uses VBA.  Other Excel programs run OK on the Win 7 machine.

Comment: Are there any macros in the before save event, or workbook open event?

Comment: When I run it the first time on Win 7, I test the program to see that it is working properly.  This executes various VBA code, eg. get a withholding amount from a look up table.  When I finish , I close Excel and choose the save changes option.  When I run it the second time is when I get the strange behavior.

Comment: It sounds as if some of the first code run is saving changes that cause the problem. Determining which of those may be the cause should be possible by looking at the individual changes made to the file for suspects and comparing to the version that runs

Comment: I have never tried opening the file and immediately closing it without saving changes. I'll give that a try and let you know.  It may be awhile because the Win 7 machine is my son's lap top which he uses in his business and I'll have to arrange to borrow it for some testing.

Comment: If that works, I'll try various small steps to sse if any thing might be the problem.  If so why would it be OK on the Vista machine?